# Build a nested dictionary with a list

Tags: python

I am struggling with how to define a list and append to it while looping through parsed json doc. I can't append to the list that's not defined. But I don't want to set to empty list, as that would override values I had in it in next iteration. This is what I have:

```
from collections import defaultdict
nested_dict = lambda: defaultdict(nested_dict)
hash = nested_dict()
   for e in decoded_jason['volumeList']:
       volumeName = e['name']
       volumeType = e['volumeType']
       if volumeType == 'Snapshot':
          consistencyGroupId = e['consistencyGroupId']
          #I am missing a step here to initialize empty list so I can append
          hash['map']['consistencyGroup'][consistencyGroupId].append(volumeName)
```

if I do this before append, it works, but then the list will be set to empty in next iteration:

```
hash['map']['consistencyGroup'][consistencyGroupId]=[]
hash['map']['consistencyGroup'][consistencyGroupId].append(volumeName)
```

Comment: Please post your JSON data, its very hard to visualize

Answer (score 2):

Make your final line be:

`hash['map']['consistencyGroup'].setdefault(consistencyGroupId, []).append(volumeName)`

`setdefault` either returns the value for the key if it's present, or, if it's not, sets it to the provided default (`[]` in this case), and then returns that.

Comment: Thank you Donnie, that works! I was trying with setdefault but I wasn't using it correctly (instead of consistencyGroupId, I had the whole hash thing.